# Eu fui banido do chat permanentemente?

Tags: suporte, chat

Ou é um erro ?

Eu entro no chat diz que preciso fazer login no StackExchange.

E quando entro na página com outras salas me diz a mesma coisa.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Que eu saiba não, o teu perfil não tem nada sobre o assunto. Não será um problema de cache ou de cookies?

Comment: Não sei. Não aconteceu isso comigo ainda.

Comment: Já experimentaste fazer login?

Comment: uashusahuash eu sempre usei o chat usando a conta do SOPt. Mas do Exchange não.

Comment: Experimenta então, não sei...

Comment: Não tenho conta no Exchange

Comment: Faz login no chat que é o mesmo que o do SOpt.

Comment: Ainda bem que deu certo ;)